# Boolean not keeping most recent value of Sharedpreference result

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

My boolean variable is not keeping the most current value of sharedprefs. In this functions it returns true of success:

```
// Method for Async. call
public boolean downloadMatchesAsync(String date) {

    brawtaAPIAdapter.runGetMatches(date, new Callback<JSONKeys>() {

        @Override
        public void success(JSONKeys jsonKeys, Response response) {

            Success = jsonKeys.isSuccess();
            message = jsonKeys.getErrorMessage();

            if (!message.isEmpty()) {
                Toast.makeText(MyApplication.getAppContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            Gson gson = new Gson();
            String jsonObject = gson.toJson(jsonKeys); //converts java object into json string'

            downloaded = Preferences.saveToPreferences(activity, ApplicationConstants.match_data, jsonObject);
            Log.d(ApplicationConstants.TAG,"In networkOperation " + downloaded); //is true at this point
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
        }
    }); // Call Async API


    return downloaded;
}
```

However when i call the function in another method in the same class it returns false here:

```
 // Method for Async. call
public void authenticateUserAsync(String email, String password) {

    brawtaAPIAdapter.runUserAuthentication(email, password, new Callback<JSONKeys>() {
        @Override
        public void success(JSONKeys jsonKeys, Response response) {
            Success = jsonKeys.isSuccess();
            message = jsonKeys.getMessage();

            if (Success) {

                boolean b = downloadMatchesAsync(date);
                Log.d(ApplicationConstants.TAG, "In authenticateUserAsync " + b); //is false at this point

                if(b){
                    Intent i = new Intent(activity, MatchSelect.class);

                    activity.startActivity(i);
                    activity.finish();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {

            Toast.makeText(MyApplication.getAppContext(), "Incorrect Credentials", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }); // Call Async API

}
```

This is the definition of my downloaded variable:

```
  public class NetworkOperations {

private BrawtaAPIAdapter brawtaAPIAdapter; // REST Adapter
private boolean Success;
private String message;
private Activity activity;
private String data;
private String date;
private boolean downloaded = false;
```

and this is the definition of my preference class:

```
 public class Preferences {

private static final String PrefName = "net.brawtasports.brawtasportsgps";

public static boolean saveToPreferences(Context context, String key, String value) {

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PrefName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString(key, value);
    return editor.commit();
}

public static String readFromPreferences(Context context, String key, String defaultValue) {

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PrefName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return sharedPreferences.getString(key, defaultValue);

}

}
```

I figure that it is a problem regarding the scope of `downloaded`. How can i solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the point here is:
In downloadMatchesAsync, variable downloaded is only changed in async method.
But in authenticateUserAsync, you use downloadMatchesAsync like a normal sync method (the value 'downloaded' is returned before the work in downloadMatchesAsync.success completed, you will see the log 'In authenticateUserAsync ' appear before 'In networkOperation ')
I think those changed below may solve your problem:

```
    private boolean downloaded = false;
private HashMap<String, Boolean> authenticateUsers = new HashMap<String, Boolean>();
public boolean downloadMatchesAsync(String date, final String email) {

brawtaAPIAdapter.runGetMatches(date, new Callback<JSONKeys>() {

    @Override
    public void success(JSONKeys jsonKeys, Response response) {

        Success = jsonKeys.isSuccess();
        message = jsonKeys.getErrorMessage();

        if (!message.isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(MyApplication.getAppContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String jsonObject = gson.toJson(jsonKeys); //converts java object into json string'

        downloaded = Preferences.saveToPreferences(activity, ApplicationConstants.match_data, jsonObject);
        Log.d(ApplicationConstants.TAG,"In networkOperation " + downloaded); //is true at this point
        // if downloaded and user is authenticated, start the activity
        if (downloaded) {
            Boolean isAuthenticated = authenticateUsers.get(email);
            if (isAuthenticated != null && isAuthenticated) {
                Intent i = new Intent(activity, MatchSelect.class);

                activity.startActivity(i);
                activity.finish();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
    }
}); // Call Async API


 return downloaded;
}
 public void authenticateUserAsync(final String email, String password) {

brawtaAPIAdapter.runUserAuthentication(email, password, new Callback<JSONKeys>() {
    @Override
    public void success(JSONKeys jsonKeys, Response response) {
        Success = jsonKeys.isSuccess();
        message = jsonKeys.getMessage();
        // store the authenticate result
        authenticateUsers.put(email, Success);
        if (Success) {

            // boolean b = downloadMatchesAsync(date);
            // check if work in downloadMatchesAsync completed;
            boolean b = downloaded;
            Log.d(ApplicationConstants.TAG, "In authenticateUserAsync " + b); //is false at this point

            if(b){
                Intent i = new Intent(activity, MatchSelect.class);

                activity.startActivity(i);
                activity.finish();
            } else {
                downloadMatchesAsync(date, email);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void failure(RetrofitError error) {

        // store the authenticate result
        authenticateUsers.put(email, false);
        Toast.makeText(MyApplication.getAppContext(), "Incorrect Credentials", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
 }); // Call Async API
```

}

Hope this help

Comment: excellent!! Ok so this works but before I accept your answer is there a way to achieve this without having a second parameter for email. This method is called somewhere else in my app but I do not need email to run it. So what i am thinking to do for those instances is to call the method like this `networkOperations.downloadMatchesAsync(date,"");` with a blank email parameter. Would this cause any issues that you can foresee?

Comment: @CastellJames the email parameter is for the case you want to start MatchSelect actitivties right after networkOperations.downloadMatchesAsync completed with an authencicated user, You can pass "" or nul to email so it's will only do the download part and don't start the MatchSelect Activity

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are passing the same `Context` object to `readFromPreferences()` and `saveToPreferences()`. By default, when you call `Activity.getSharedPreferences()`, Android will create a file with the Activity's name as prefix, so you must pass the same Activity to read from the same file.

If you want to store or read data from a global preferences file which is not tied to an Activity, use the *application context* instead:

```
public static String readFromPreferences(Context context, String key, String defaultValue) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(PrefName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return sharedPreferences.getString(key, defaultValue);
}
```

Comment: OK good point. You just taught me something. However that did not solve my problem. I also updated the first code snippet as i made a mistake as to where 'downloaded' was returning true-please look at downloadMatchesAsync() again. It returns true right save is successful but the value is then false right before it reaches the return statement of my downloadMatchesAsync(). I figure that it is a problem regarding the scope of downloaded. How can i solve this?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do with the "downloaded" variable but since you perform an asynchronous call in "downloadMatchesAsync", it will first be "false" when the method returns immediately the first time after initiating the call, then it will be updated to true when the callback is complete which seems perfectly normal to me. What is the purpose of this "downloaded" variable and why do you return its value from this method ?